# cocoapod `[!] Unable to find a specification for 'xxxx~>xx'` with private spec

Tags: ios, git, rspec, cocoapods

I have a private spec , and have a test spec file as (testspec.podspec,tag = 0.2.0) on private spec.

when I use `pod search testspec.podspec`,I can get it:

`-> testspec (0.2.0)
   test spec
   pod 'testspec', '~> 0.2.0'
   - Homepage: https://github.com/wangweijia/cocoapods_test.git
   - Source:   https://github.com/wangweijia/cocoapods_test.git
   - Versions: 0.2.0 [repo_test repo]`

but when I `pod install` with my project:

podfile:`pod 'testspec', '~> 0.2.0'`

it say: `[!] Unable to find a specification for 'testspec.podspec~>0.2.0'`

help me!!!

Comment: Homepage and source are same in your podspec. Try Home page https://github.com/wangweijia nad keep source as same

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `source` to your podfile.

```
source 'http://github.com/MyPrivateRepo/Specs.git'
```

You might also need to add the master repo itself:

```
source 'source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git''
```